# react - select causing page to scroll down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select in my project.

I have a numerous selects and I need the selects to be open so I am using
the prop menuIsOpen={true} 
but for some reason this prop causing the page to scroll down to almost the middle of the page.

when I am setting menuIsOpen={false} the page is not scrolled down but it does not solve the problem because I must have the selects open

is anyone familiar with this problem?

```
      <Select
        styles={filter.name !== "More" ? basicStyles : moreStyles}
        isMulti={filter.name !== "colorType" ? true : false}
        options={options}
        hideSelectedOptions={false}
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        placeholder=""
        value={selectedValues ? selectedValues : []}
        isClearable={false}
        isSearchable={false}
        onChange={addSelectFilter}
        components={{ MultiValueLabel: customMultiValueLabel }}
        blurInputOnSelect={false}
        classNamePrefix={filter.name === "More" ? "more" : "basic-drop"}
        className={filter.name === "More" ? "more-select-container" : undefined}
        menuIsOpen={
          filter.name === "More" ? undefined : menuIsOpen ? true : undefined
        }
      />
```

Answer (score 8):

This problem is caused by the default value of the [`menuPosition` prop](https://react-select.com/props) being `absolute`. On a long dropdown list, the dropdown area overflows the screen and makes the browser scroll down.

Add `menuPosition="fixed"` as a prop to the `Select` component and it should work. Then you also do not need to set the z-index manually.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and it was quite annoying ! 
I resolved it by setting some custom style and adding the props for the portal like:

```js
    const customSelectProps = {
        menuPortalTarget: document.getElementById('root'),
        customStyles: {
            menuPortal: base => {
                const { zIndex, ...rest } = base;
                return { ...rest, zIndex: 9999 };
            },
        },
    };
```

Comment: hey man thanks for answering, it solved the scroll but now the list menu disappeared

Comment: did you set the z-index ? for the menuPortalTarget you can also try document.body (or create a custom div yourself)

Comment: there is no custom styles prop and when I am using menuPortalTarget it causes the menu to close

Comment: There is one, its "styles"
https://react-select.com/props 
You can then bind the style to your control

Answer (score 2):

I added `menuShouldScrollIntoView={false}` to Select component and it helped me solve the problem

Comment: Can confirm that this worked for `react-select` v`5.3.2`

Answer (score 1):

Adding menuPlacement= 'auto' or top (anything beside "bottom") fixed this issue for me.